# Nativescript Image to Buffer to Use With Node Module Vibrant

Tags: node.js, nativescript

I'm using the `native_script camera module`. I'm able to take an image which is saved to my gallery, I can display it in `HTML` but I don't understand how to use the image with the node module `vibrant`. The code is tested on an `Iphone 6s` (real device, no simulator).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
require("nativescript-nodeify")
const Vibrant = require('node-vibrant');
import * as camera from "nativescript-camera";
import * as  imageModule from "ui/image";


@Component({
  selector: 'ns-snapshot',
  templateUrl: './snapshot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snapshot.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id,
})
export class SnapshotComponent implements OnInit {
    result: string;
    image: null;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
          console.log("checking camera")
          camera.requestPermissions() // works
    }


    getColor(imgSrc) {
        console.log("Analyzing color");
        Vibrant.from(imgSrc).getPalette((err, palette) => { // failing complains that imgSrc is not a valid HTMLImageElement
              console.log("err", err);
              console.log("palette", palette);
              this.result = palette.toString();

        })
    }
    takeSnapshot() {
          console.log("taking snapshot")
          camera.takePicture()
              .then( (imageAsset) => {
                  console.log("Result is an image asset instance"); // works
                  console.log("imageAsset", imageAsset)
                  this.image = new imageModule.Image();
                  this.image.src = imageAsset;
                  console.log("image.src", this.image);
                  console.log("image.srcII", this.image.src);
                  console.log("image.srcIII", this.image.src.ios);
                  this.getColor(this.image.src);
              }).catch( (err) => {
              console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
          });
    }

}
```

The logs:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/snapshot/snapshot.component.js:61:24: image.src Image(14)
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/snapshot/snapshot.component.js:63:28: image.srcII {
"_observers": {},
"_options": {
"keepAspectRatio": true
},
"_ios": {}
}
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/snapshot/snapshot.component.js:65:32: image.srcIII <PHAsset: 0x11fef9300> ADFBE7B0-7A38-4F12-8390-0D77D72709D0/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (3024x4032), creationDate=2018-11-05 08:56:25 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/snapshot/snapshot.component.js:45:20: Analyzing color with test
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/snapshot/snapshot.component.js:69:24: Error -> Can't find variable: HTMLImageElement
```

I also tried to pass `this.image` because it looks similar to [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

#### EDIT with saving the file explicitly:

```
import { fromAsset } from "image-source";
import { knownFolders, path } from "file-system"
```

....

```
camera.takePicture()
    .then( (imageAsset) => {
       console.log("Result is an image asset instance");
       console.log("imageAsset", imageAsset);
       this.image = new imageModule.Image();
       this.image.src = imageAsset;
       fromAsset(imageAsset)
           .then((imageSource) => {
                const folder = knownFolders.temp();
                const filePath = path.join(folder.path, "test" + ".png");
                console.log('saving to', filePath)
                if (imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, "png", 90)) {
                       this.getColor(filePath);
                }
});
```

### Question

Question how to pass the path/ convert the image to a buffer in a way that vibrant can process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from camera plugin is not a file but a image asset. You will have to write it to a file then pass it on to Vibrant.

```
import { fromAsset } from "image-source";

fromAsset(imageAsset)
  .then((imageSource) => {
    if (imageSource.saveToFile(YourFilePath, "jpg", 90)) {
      Vibrant.from(YourFilePath)...
      ....
      ....
    }
  });
```

Between, {N} just provides a JavaScript runtime that is not a Node Engine / Browser, so if your libraries depend on any Node / Browser specific apis, it won't work inside {N} environment. You will have to find the native equivalent of same.

There is also [nativescript-nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify) that implements only a limited set of node apis like file, stream etc.,

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried it with `image-source` but I just get a different error: `file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1743:28: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document` . See the edit above for the code. I already use: `nativescript-nodeify`

Comment: Is there any way to figure out which node-modules can be used with `nativescript-nodeify`? Because document is probably [the dom document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp). So do I need a polyfill for this?

Comment: There is no easy way to find it. This list will give you some heads-up on supported apis - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify/blob/master/shims.json I don't think you can use Vibrant with {N}. Would you mind explaining what's the purpose of this module, so I may be able to give you a native equivalent solution should be used in iOS / Android.

Comment: I'm currently using this [native script module](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-image-colors) but I also ran into problems. Also, the Vibrant module looks better and has more maintainers, would be sad if it cannot be used.